# fatal error: open.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c

I want to use [open_excl(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/open_excl) in order to open a file for exclusive writing.

I wrote:

```
#include <open.h>

int main(int c, char* v[]){
    int fp = open_excl("my_file");
    return 0;
}
```

Now:
gcc -Wall file.c -o out.a

And I get a fatal compiler error: open.h: No such file or directory

How come? do I have a broken path problem? Missing a link to a library?
Wrong version of gcc? I'm using 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)

Comment: That's not a standard function anywhere (neither in C, C++, POSIX or Windows). Perhaps you should stick to the [POSIX standard `open` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) with the `O_EXCL` flag instead?

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/open_excl

Comment: `#include "open.h"` perhaps?

Comment: So, maybe I should go with 
`fp = fopen(filename, "w");
flock(fp, LOCK_EX);`

Comment: But flock expect an integer that stands for a file descriptor while fopen returns a FILE*. Was trying to google how to get the descriptor from the FILE, no success yet.

Comment: @Zack *Was trying to google how to get the descriptor from the FILE, no success yet* You want [`fileno()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fileno.html).

Comment: There is no standard function `open_excl`. I don't have man pages for `open_excl`. I don't have `open.h`.

Comment: @Zack also, flock is a *completely* different thing.

Comment: "*I have a broken path problem*" no, but `linux.die.net/` is broken, just drop it from your link list.

Answer (score 3):

The `open_excl` is not a standard function; I don't have `open.h` on my Linux system. As the [documentation on linux.die.net](https://linux.die.net/man/3/open_excl) says:

> `open_excl` opens the file `filename` for writing and returns the file handle. The file may not exist before the call to `open_excl`. The file will be created with mode `0600`.
>
> [...] `open_excl` relies on the `O_EXCL` flag to open [...]

Thus you could achieve the same with

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

By calling it as follows:

```
int fd = open(filename, O_EXCL|O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 0600);
```

To wrap the file descriptor into `FILE *` use the `fdopen` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *fp = fdopen(fd);
```

Comment: OK, but after opening a file like this and getting an int fd, how onw uses it for functions like fgets or fprintf that excpect a FILE*?

Comment: @Zack use fdopen

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you include any header file, the compiler looks for the same in standard directory if angular brackets are used  `#include <open.h>` and in project directory if quotes are used `#include "open.h"`.

So you can first check if you have the open.h file in the standard directory (which probably is not the case), you can download and copy the header file in your local directory and use quotes include the same.